# Why am I getting uninitialized constant error for model name on another branch?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

I made `Role` model on one branch on github and run `db:migrate`.
When switch to new branch from master(scratch) and want to connect with it in `rails console` I get "uninitialized constant" error message.

My question is how is possible to get this error if I already sent table `roles` to database, and should be allowed to access is from all branches?

Comment: Does the relevant model file exist under `app/models/role.rb` in the new branch?

Comment: It's not about having database table (which indeed you have, BTW), it's about having `Role` class, which you don't have after you switch to another branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails you need a model to access database table via ORM. Model is a regular ruby class with some magic around it.

Since you no not have one on the other branch - you're getting the error about trying to access non-existent ruby class.

You can still access the table via raw sql queries via `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`